# writeRaster in R produces GeoTIFF with only max or min values

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I have produced some maps in R with values between 0 and 1000.

`plot(my.map)` shows that there is a range of values between 0 and 1000 in `my.map`. Here is an example of what a plot looks like in R

[image: example plot of my.map with clear range of colours indicating values between 0 and 1000]

But if I then use writeRaster to create a GeoTIFF (with libraries 'raster' and 'gdal' loaded)

```
writeRaster(my.map,
            format = 'GTiff',
            filename = "myMapGTiff")
```

...the output, when viewed in ArcMap, has values that are either 0 or 1000 and nothing inbetween.

[image: example ArcMap plot of the GeoTIFF showing only two colours (0 or 1000) although the legend has a colour ramp displaying that there were options for displaying intermediate values as different colours]

Does anyone know why this is?

I have managed to writeRaster to ASCII instead and preserve the values, but I would like to know what the issue is with the GeoTIFFs as they tend to be more flexible to work with.

Comment: If you read them back into R do they look okay? That might tell us if the problem is in the writing of the GTiff or in Arc's reading and interpretation of it.

Comment: Oh you are right, reading it back into R looks ok, so it is arcMap's reading of the geoTiff that needs attention...I'll dig deeper. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the default symbology in arcMap is "stretch" by type "standard deviations" which is giving the erroneous 0/1000 values map. Changing this to any other stretch type once again resolves the intermediate values (to 0-1000). Even more curiously if you select standard deviations again it now looks correct. I'm still not certain why this is, but at least I know to look for it and know how to change it to be correct. So thanks for the prompting @spacedman.

Comment: Because rasters can be large and computing statistics can take time, sometimes these get stored in metadata (eg in an .xml "sidecar" file) and end up being incorrect with reference to the actual data until the system notices and updates the metadata by reading through the whole raster and doing the calculations. I suspect something like this may have happened.